# Serialize an object with no data in Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Is it possible to serialize an object with no fields in Jackson using only annotations?  When I attempt to serialize such an object with no annotations I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class [redacted].SubjectObjectFeatureExtractor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
```

I have examined the [list of Jackson annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) without seeing a way to annotate the class as having no serializable data.  I tried putting `@JsonCreator` on the empty constructor (not expecting it to work, since it's a deserialization annotation), and I got the same error.  There are no accessors or fields to put `@JsonProperty` on. Any ideas?

**Update:** The reason for this is that I have a list of objects which represent transformations which can be applied to a certain type of data. Some of these transformations are defined by parameters which needs to be serialized, but some of these are parameter-less (the data-less objects in question).  I'd like to be able to serialize and deserialize a sequence of these transformations.  Also, I'm using `DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL` so that the class name will be serialized.

**Update:** An example class would be

```
class ExtractSomeFeature implements FeatureExtractor<SomeOtherType> {
    public void extractFeature(SomeOtherType obj, WeightedFeatureList output) {
          // do stuff
    }
 }
```

I don't particularly care how the JSON for this looks like, as long as I can deserialize `List<FeatureExtractor>`s properly.  My impression is that using default typing, the expected JSON would be something like:

```
['com.mycompany.foo.ExtractSomeFeature', {}]
```

Other sub-classes of `FeatureExtractor` would have real parameters, so they would presumably look something like:

```
[`com.mycompany.foo.SomeParameterizedFeature', {some actual JSON stuff in here}]
```

I think I could use `@JsonValue` on some `toJSONString()` method to return `{}`, but if possible I'd like to hide such hackery from end-users who will be creating `FeatureExtractor` sub-classes.

Comment: So you just want an empty `{}`? What purpose does that have?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I've updated the question in response to your questions.

Comment: Please give an example of the type of object you'd want to serialize and what you'd expect the generated JSON to be.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Question updated.

Comment: There is a relevant issue in Jackon's JIRA: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-201?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab, which seems to indicate the issue was fixed, so that POJOs with other Jackson annotations (e.g. @JsonCreator on the empty constructor, I assume) should not throw an exception. However, this does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer to [disable `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40972899/2171120) is global, and you therefore might not wish to apply it.

The answer to [add any serialisation annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21319219/2171120) showed the correct (as in: the Javadoc of `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` suggests it) way to fix it, but only with a hackish or an unrelated annotation.

By merely adding…

```
@JsonSerialize
```

… to my class (not even parenthesēs after it, lest alone arguments!) I was able to produce the same effect (as, again, indicated by the Javadoc of `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS`).

Answer (score 13):

You have to configure your object mapper to support this case.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = ...
  objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
```

The documentation of this feature can be found here : [Fail on empty beans](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

> Feature that determines what happens when no accessors are found for a
>   type (and there are no annotations to indicate it is meant to be
>   serialized). If enabled (default), an exception is thrown to indicate
>   these as non-serializable types; if disabled, they are serialized as
>   empty Objects, i.e. without any properties.

Comment: This answer doesn't rely on a hack and therefore is more "correct". Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Adding the following annotation onto the class seems to solve the problem:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
```

Adding an unrelated annotated like

```
@JsonRootName("fred")
```

also seems to fix it. This seems to match the claim in the JIRA ticket that adding any Jackson annotation to the class will prevent the exception. However, it appears adding annotations within the class does not.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get your question, but perhaps you want [JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_DEFAULT), [JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_NULL), or [JsonInclude.Include. NON_EMPTY](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_EMPTY).